# Parsley validation return false on first click and true on second click of button

Tags: javascript, parsley.js

I am doing form validation where I have some input fields and select box.

> Problem is when I click on submit button its not able to call validate function on first click but when I do second click, complier able to call validate and return true and my form get validated Code is as under :-

JS code

```
function validateOnSubmit(){
    $('form[data-validate="parsley"]').each(function () {

        if($(this).parsley().validate()) {
            validated = true;
        }
    });
}
```

HTML Code

```
                <form id="billPaymentSubmit" name="billPaymentSubmit" data-validate="parsley" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="if(event.keyCode==13) { return false; };" action="" method="POST">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <div class="rows p-n">
                                                    <div class="col-lg-12 m-sm" id="quickPayOption">
                                                            <label class="text-xs font-bold"> <span class="">* QUICK PAY OPTIONS
                                                            </span>
                                                            </label>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="rows p-n">
                                                    <div class="col-lg-3 checkbox i-checks m-n ">
                                                        <label class="radio m-r-lg" for="quickPayOption_J"> 
                                                        <input id="quickPayOption_J" name="bill.quickPayOpted" class="input-panel" onclick="setQuickPayOption(this)" type="radio" value="0"> 
                                                                <i></i>
                                                        <span class="">JomPay
                                                                </span>
                                                        </label>

                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-lg-6 checkbox i-checks m-n">
                                                        <label class=" radio m-r-lg" for="quickPayOption_O">
                                                            <input id="quickPayOption_O" name="bill.quickPayOpted" class="input-panel" onclick="setQuickPayOption(this)" type="radio" value="1" checked="checked"> <i></i>
                                                        <span class="">Other Payments
                                                                </span>
                                                        <br>
                                                        <span class="text-xs">(Other billers - Credit cards/Loans/Mobile prepaid)
                                                            </span>
                                                        </label>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <hr width="100%">
                                                    <div class="clearer"></div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>



            <!-- ************************ other payment start *******************-->

                                <div class="form-group" id="otherPaymentDiv">
                                    <div class="rows p-n">
                                                    <div class="col-lg-6 cols">
                                                                    <div class="m-sm">

                                                                <label class="text-xs font-bold"> <span class="">* BILLING ORGANIZATION
                                                                </span>
                                                                </label> <br>
                                                                <div class="select2-container parsley-validated parsley-success" id="s2id_billerOrg" title="" style="width: 100%;"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="select2-choice" tabindex="-1">   <span class="select2-chosen" id="select2-chosen-2">CELCOM ACCESS mobileReload</span><abbr class="select2-search-choice-close"></abbr>   <span class="select2-arrow" role="presentation"><b role="presentation"></b></span></a><label for="s2id_autogen2" class="select2-offscreen"></label><input class="select2-focusser select2-offscreen" type="text" aria-haspopup="true" role="button" aria-labelledby="select2-chosen-2" id="s2id_autogen2"></div><select id="billerOrg" name="payeeCode" class="parsley-validated select2-offscreen parsley-success" style="width:100%;" data-required="true" onchange="e2esubmit(true,'/2FA/processEnquiry.do?token=457b352120cef08ac2f32624facff0e6&amp;keyId=0&amp;_p=0&amp;__c=101-50-BA6B010008814303EBBBC6475162EE5A')" title="" tabindex="-1"><option value="" alt="">Select Organisation</option><option value="00000003" selected="selected" alt="CELCOM">CELCOM ACCESS mobileReload</option><option value="00000013" alt="Extra Space Segambut">Extra Space Segambut</option><option value="00000001" alt="MAXI">MAXIS hotlink mobile reload</option><option value="00000026" alt="Mobifon 018">Mobifon 018</option><option value="00000153" alt=" Card Center"> Card Center</option><option value="00000154" alt=" Loans"> Loans</option></select>

                                                                <a href="asdf" class="select2-icon">
                                                                    <i id="billerlist-ajax" class="-seelist color-icon text-lg"></i>
                                                                </a>

                                                                            <!-- <div id="add-local-error"></div> -->
                                                                    <div class="errorMsg parsley-error-list hide">This value is required.</div>
                                                                    </div>

                                                    </div>

                                                    <div class="col-lg-6 cols">
                                                        <div class="m-sm">

                                                                <label class="text-xs font-bold"> <span class="">BILLER DESCRIPTION
                                                                </span>
                                                                </label> <br>
                                                                <input id="billerdesc-addbiller-precapture" name="bill.billerDesc" class="form-control parsley-validated parsley-success" readonly="readonly" autocomplete="off" data-required="true" onkeypress="if(event.keyCode == 13){return false;};" type="text" value="CELCOM ACCESS mobileReload">

                                                                <div class="errorMsg parsley-error-list hide">This value is required.</div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="clearer"></div>
                                                </div>



                                                <div class="rows m-t-md">
                                                        <div class="col-lg-6">

                                                                <label class="text-xs font-bold"> <span class="">FROM
                                                                </span>
                                                                </label> <br>
                                                                <div>






                                                                        <select id="fromAccount" name="bill.fromAccount" class="form-control account-select parsley-validated parsley-success" data-required="true"><option value="">Select Account</option><option value="10" selected="selected">Current Acct Normal 248-300-355-4 (MYR)  50,000.00</option><option value="9">Current Acct Normal 248-300-328-7 (MYR)  10,000,000.00</option></select>


                                                                        <div class="errorMsg parsley-error-list hide">This value is required.</div>




                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    <div class="col-lg-3">

                                                                <label class="text-xs font-bold"> 
                                                                    <span class="">WHEN
                                                                    </span>
                                                                </label> 

                                                                <br>
                                                              <div class="text-lg">
                                                                10 Mar 2017
                                                            </div>

                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-lg-3">

                                                            </div>

                                                    <div class="clearer"></div>
                                                        </div>



                                                <div class="rows m-t-md m-b-md">
                                                    <div class="col-lg-6">

                                                                <label class="text-xs font-bold"> <span class="">AMOUNT
                                                                    </span>
                                                                </label>
                                                                <div>


                                                                        <select id="mobileTopUp" name="bill.billAmount" class="form-control m-b account-select parsley-validated parsley-success" data-required="true"><option value="">Select Amount</option><option value="1">50</option></select>

                                                                            <div class="errorMsg parsley-error-list hide">This value is required.</div>



                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>


                                                    <div class="clearer"></div>
                                                </div>

                                            <div class="form-group">






                                                </div>

                                                <div class="clearer"></div>

                                                <div class="row m-t-lg">
                                                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                                                        <div class="doc-buttons">
                                                            <button onclick="e2eValidateSubmit(validateOnSubmit(),true,'/2FA/processSubmit.do?token=457b352120cef08ac2f32624facff0e6&amp;keyId=0&amp;_p=0&amp;__c=101-53-BA6B010008814303EBBBC6475162EE5A');return false;" id="btnsubmit" class="btn btn-s-md btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit">
                                                                <span class="">Continue
                                                                </span>
                                                            </button>

                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div> 

                                            </div>      






                                    <div class="clearer"></div>     













                <!-- ************************ other payment end ******************-->                   

            </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you are using custom select box and  when user will click on div having class **select2-container**, parsley not able to validate it.

Also if you want to validate all fields you need to make a counter and only pass **true** when all fields get verified. Code is as under :-

```
            function validateOnSubmit() {
                var validated = false,
                    count = 0;

                if($("#quickPayOption_O:checked").length > 0 ){

                    $('#otherPaymentDiv').find('.parsley-validated').each(function () {

                        if(!$(this).hasClass("select2-container")){
                            if($(this).parsley().validate()) {
                                count++;
                            }

                            if(count === $('#otherPaymentDiv .parsley-validated').length -1){
                                validated = true;
                            }
                        }

                    });

                    $('#jomPayDiv').find('.parsley-validated').each(function() {
                        $(this).parsley('removeConstraint','required');
                        flag = true;
                    }); 

                    return validated;
                };

        }
```